# Need a way to run a script on windows boot up prior to a user logging in

Tags: windows-server-2003, boot, scripting, startup

I need to run a custom script which runs when Windows boots up.I know its possible to run it when a user logs in but I want to run it when the system reboots i.e. prior to a user logging in.
The OS in question is Windows 2003 and Windows 2000

Answer (score 11):

You can use a Group Policy (or the local policy) to assign a startup script; you can configure it in the section `Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)`.

You can also use `Scheduled Tasks` to configure a task to run at computer startup.

Answer (score 0):

Run some kind of widnows Services which run just after systems starts.

Answer (score 0):

Startup script in Computer Setting in group policy?

Answer (score -2):

I guess I found the answer here.

http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/startup_0401.html

I will try it and tell if it works

Comment: Wrong.
HKXY\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunX keys, as well as the Startup folder(s), are processed by at user logon. If nobody logs in, your program will not be executed. You should use Scheduled Taksks or a policy.